# Can I convert empty strings to NULL with a Codeigniter validation rule?

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3

I would like to convert all my POST values from `''` to `NULL` automatically with a Codeigniter validation rule. Is it possible?

Here is my helper, which is working fine with text and numbers :

```
function empty2null($value)
{
    return $value === '' ? null : $value;
}
```

Can I define it as a validation rule (prepping?) somewhere?
How to do this?

Afterwards I would like to send it as a proper `NULL` value to Doctrine.

Comment: Your function does what you want. Are you asking how do implement `validation` in CodeIgniter? If so, this is not an appropriate question for SO. I suggest you go to [the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) and delete this question.

Comment: No, I know very well how to implement validation rules in CI. What I'm asking is IF it is possible to implement my function as a rule and force CI to trigger it? I tried to implement it, but the custom function is not triggered when the POST value is empty (It seems CI is making no validation on empty strings unfortunately).

Comment: I had forgotten that empty fields are not evaluated unless the field also uses a 'required', 'isset', or 'matches' rule. If any of those are set then the field will be evaluated. I don't think any of those is going to help you. It is probably going to be easier to loop through the post data and convert to NULL before you run form validation.

Comment: You are right. I think I will call my helper function directly in my doctrine setters at the end.